# How can I use NSAlert without any icon?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, nsalert

I want to create a `NSAlert` with `beginSheetModalForWindow`, without any icon in alertstyle among `NSWarningAlertStyle`, `NSInformationalAlertStyle`, `NSCriticalAlertStyle` ?

Also if I use a functional API such as `NSBeginAlertSheet`, `NSBeginCriticalAlertSheet`, how do I remove the icon from it ?

Comment: There's something like a standard style for alerts users expect and are used to.. so instead of using non-standard of funny-looking alerts with empty icons you might consider embracing the standard behaviour of the platform instead

Answer (score 4):

**You can do some hack.**

[image]

Here a [transparent image (click to download)](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/6143821/transparent-image-2k?da=y) is used.

Comment: What a nice solution! +1 :)

Comment: you could also do `alert.image = [NSImage new];`

Comment: @ThePulsingEye, but there is still blank space where the icon should be showing up...

Comment: @AdamJohns: In that case you always have an option to use custom window, but since the question was for using Alert, the above answers that way

Answer (score 0):

You can not!
NSAlert always shows the application icon: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/Reference/Reference.html

> icon: Icon for the alert. nil restores the application icon.
>
> Discussion:
> By default, the image is the application icon, accessed via the application bundle’s NSApplicationIcon property.

Consider to sub-class NSAlert or create your own dialog.